# What can cause Cobertura to throw a NoClassDefFoundError when attempting to instrument code?

Tags: java, maven, cobertura, surefire

We're current using Maven 3 and getting an issue where Cobertura 2.7 keeps throwing a NoClassDefFoundError on one of the classes and consequently the unit tests fail that have a dependency on this class.

When running this without Cobertura the unit tests pass no problem.

Cobertura is invoked using the following:

```
mvn clean cobertura:cobertura
```

And testing normally with the Surefire plugin just:

```
mvn clean test
```

The class that this is failing on is an abstract generic class one of our engineers implemented which I think might be what's causing Cobertura to barf. The class is of the structure:

```
public abstract class MyClass <T> {

    public abstract String myMethod1(final T param);

    public abstract void myMethod2(final T param);
}
```

Then the implementation class extends this like so:

```
public class MyImplClass <MyType> {

    @Override
    public String myMethod1(final MyType param) {
        return "foo";
    }

    @Override
    public void myMethod2(final MyType param) {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Is the inheritance from an abstract generic class what is causing Cobertura to fail here?

As a quick note, this was tried with several minor version of Maven 3, all with the same result.